# I'm getting two duplicate slides. Whereas I need only one

Tags: beamer, presentations

I want the following information to be on only one slide, whereas I'm getting two copies of the same slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\subsection{Compression}
 \begin{frame}{Merge Example}
\frametitle{Compression}
Consider N to be the number of images in the database.
 \begin{itemize}[<+->]
 \item Without pre-processing
  \begin{itemize}[<.->]
    \item The database needs $\mathit{N\times m\times n}$ pixels for storage
   \end{itemize}
\item With NMF with sparseness constraint
 \begin{itemize}[<.->]
 \item If A is the dictionary atom.
     \item Then database needs $\mathit{(A\times m\times n)+A \times N}$ pixels for storage
     \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
To achieve compression, $\mathit{A}$ is chosen such that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathit{A (N+m\times n)}}{\mathit{N\times m\times n}}< 1
\label{eqn4}
\end{equation}
Necessary (but not sufficient) condition for compression using this algorithm are \textemdash
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\mathit{A}< \mathit{N}$
\item $\mathit{A}< \mathit{(m\times n)}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 3):

You use

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item ...
  \item ...
\end{itemize}
```

This means that on the first slide only the first item is shown.
So a second slide is inserted showing the second item too.

If you only want a single slide showing everything from the beginning, just delete `[<+->]`.